# App rejected from app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have submitted an app on Appstore.

The app got rejected and here is the Apple Response

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 9.3.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

Specifically, the app loads indefinitely upon launch. Please see the attached screenshots for additional details."

I have tested it in multiple ways as told by Apple but unable to reproduce the issue. Moreover Apple says it "the app loads indefinitely upon launch" well the screen shot they have send is not of launch screen but that is of a view controller which comes after launch screen.

Please guide me to overcome this issue.

Comment: can anybody tell me why so much down votes?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the tester was confused by the contents of the post-launch view controller.  You should provide some guidance to the user on how to use the app once it launches with no data.  For example, you might have a `UILabel` that appears to new users explaining how to start using the app.  Effective user onboarding is practically a whole discipline.  You can seem some good (and entertaining) analyses of user onboarding processes at https://www.useronboard.com/

Comment: issue resolved. I asked App store to give me some details of the problem because not even a single time my app got stuck, as they mentioned, and then Apple told me that my app is approved. It seems there is some sort of automated testing system rejected the app

Comment: So it sounds like you communicated with them and someone checked the automated process and then they thought everything was okay?

Comment: I made no changes because on my side app was working fine. I spend 3 days and not even single time I was able to replicate the issue they mentioned. So I ask them to provide me some details. The next thing is Apple approved my app instead of providing any details.

Comment: This was the reply

Hello,

Thank you for your response and for the information you have provided.

We will continue with the review of your app and inform you of any additional issues.

Best Regards,
App Store Review

Comment: How frustrating!  Sorry you had to deal with that, but congrats on getting the approval!